# Is there a robust way for a child process to signal readyness to its parent?

Tags: process, signals

I have a (Java) process which is staring a separate process `foo`.  `foo` takes some number of seconds to start up, then is really running.  Control returns back to the parent process as soon as `foo` is started, but not necessarily ready.

Note also that `foo` writes human-readable output to both `stdout` and, in debug mode, `stderr`.

The options I'm aware of:

1. `sleep` the parent process for `n` seconds, where `n` is theoretically larger than `foo` will ever take.
2. Have the parent process looking for something special in the child's `stdout` or `stderr`, and block until it's seen.
3. Touch some sort of marker file in the OS when `foo` is ready, and have the parent process watch that file.

I don't really like any of these options (1. has a race condition, 2. involves matching magic strings, and 3. risks multiple `foo` processes colliding).  Going the other way (parent to child) I could send a signal to communicate, but I'm not aware of a better way for the child process to communicate its state to the parent.

Comment: I've voted to close this as **too broad** since [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) is an extensively documented realm with many possibilities (semaphores, pipes, *signals*, etc), of which you seem to be mostly unaware. But now you know what it is called, you can do some research and if there's any confusion come back with a more specific question (or ask it on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), which is probably more appropriate for cross-platform Java).  BTW, I intentionally emphasized *signals*, although they are a little less cross-platform.

Comment: @goldilocks agreed, there are numerous ways to IPC.  I'm curious specifically what is a robust way for a process to indicate it's "ready", since control returning to the parent process isn't sufficient.

Comment: In a unix context *signals* are ideal, but Java throws a bit of a wrench into that...so if both processes are JVM processes, once again this is really a Java question.   Your concern about "magic strings" WRT #2 is misplaced -- this makes any and all communication protocols, including IP, TCP, HTTP, etc. a bad practice since protocols do mean hardcoded formats.  There is no way around that, which is why there are protocol specifications.   By analogy, is speaking in a particular human language a bad "magic string" based practice?  What are the alternatives?

Comment: @goldilocks My Java process is starting a non-JVM process.  My issue with "magic strings" is that the child process currently prints something like `Program is now running...` but there's nothing stopping the developer of the child process from changing that; the output is for users, it's not documented behavior.  On the other hand, it is documented to listen for `SIGHUP` and `SIGINT` to terminate.  We could explore making some string of text in its output part of its documented API, but that isn't the case today.  I'm looking for `SIGINT`-like behavior the child can send to the parent.

Comment: This is a programming question and belongs on [so]. The most natural method is for the parent to open a pipe and for the child to write a byte to it or close it.

Comment: @Gilles I don't see how this is a programming question.  I mention that my process is written in Java for completeness, but my question is (in theory) language agnostic.  I'm asking about the behavior of processes in Unix, and how a child can talk back to it's parent.  When you say "open a pipe" I assume you don't mean to stdout or stderr, do you?

Comment: @dimo414 This is a programming question since you're writing a program and this is about how to design it. The pipe can be on any file descriptor. It's up to you.

Comment: I don’t understand how you’re allocating your “*(Option X)* could block the parent process if `foo` (the child process) blocks” criterion to Option 2 but not Option 3.  Surely it will be true of any reliable option (which Option 1 is not; it’s throwing darts in the dark).  By definition, you want the parent process to wait until the child is fully started and (by means as yet TBD) reports this status back to the parent.  So, if something goes wrong in the child and it never achieves readiness (or never reports it), then the parent will (and should) block forever.

Comment: @G-Man absolutely, I'm not sure what I was getting at.  Removed.

Answer (score 2):

The child could send a signal to the parent. `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` exist for this kind of *ad hoc* situation and could be ideal here.

Your application can find its parent's process id easily enough with the Java equivalent of `getppid()`, or as an alternative perhaps you could have the parent pass its own PID (`$$`) on the command line as an argument that your Java code could pick up.

Comment: This is exactly what I was driving at.   I don't think Java has standard facilities for sending signals, but it has some for handling them.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like getting the process ID is so simple either...so this vs. a [pipe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html) is sort of a matter of what style of "robustness" is required.